# postgresql agg function that returns an array with single quotes around items

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this very simple query which it returns an array of municipality identifiers, that separates them with a comma and has double quotes around each item. I want to be able to surround these double quotes with single quotes

```
select json_agg(ssn) from sde.muns
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give your expected output?

Comment: Doesn't that make it invalid JSON? Or do you want the result as a string?

Comment: just single quote around each item. result can be a string

Comment: That's not an array. It's a json object that contains a json array. Are you maybe looking for `string_agg()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have:

```
t=# with c(v) as (select * from generate_series(1020,1029))
select json_agg(v::text) from c;
                                     json_agg
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ["1020", "1021", "1022", "1023", "1024", "1025", "1026", "1027", "1028", "1029"]
(1 row)
```

so you can:

```
t=# with c(v) as (select * from generate_series(1020,1029))
select translate(json_agg(v::text)::text,'"',$$'$$) from c;
                                    translate
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ['1020', '1021', '1022', '1023', '1024', '1025', '1026', '1027', '1028', '1029']
(1 row)
```

which of course is not valid json any more. And I assumed you can have only numbers, so no accidental double quote to take care of